# Hi, I am using android studio and I'm am getting this error about duplicated dependencies but I'm not sure where to look to be able to fix the issue

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

here is a print out of the error.

Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:16.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$ConditionalUserProperty found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Event found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$UserProperty found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Param found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.4.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:16.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1) Duplicate class  in this classes keep 1 library and remove other one.You can find out which one is most important by trial and error

Comment: Some times after adding/changing dependencies in buld file this would be happen. Try to delete all folders in Project->app->build directory and build your project again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your gradle

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: tried the above and still producing the above error